# Order by not working in my SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
order by no_of_products desc;
```

why the code above is working and the code below is not working. what should I do to make the below code work.

```
order by no_of_products sold desc;
```

or

```
order by no_of_products sold' desc;
```

Comment: add you complete query

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the separator between order by columns

```
order by no_of_products desc, sold desc;
```

*(or using an alias in wrong place)*

or if you have column with space use backtics

```
order by `no_of_products sold` desc;
```

*But i suggets you of not the use column name with space ..*

Comment: i need to have space after products i.e. the alias name should be no_of_products sold. Is it possible to keep the alias name like this or not possible to have space in alias name?